# char.js overlapping bar columns when using type: 'time'

Tags: chart.js

It seems chart.js is overlapping columns whenever I use the `type: "time"` in the `xAxes`:

```
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }],
         xAxes : [{
             type: 'time'
         }],
    },
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/owy49hqh/11/)

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the overlapping problem is due to the bar size calculation is base on the number of ticks in the time scale. Under the original getRule function in the controller.bar.js:
`var tickSize = fullSize / scale.ticks.length;`

The problem happened when the time scale is optimised with step size > 1, causing error in the bar size calculation. The bar size becomes bigger and overlaps to the neighbouring bar. The correct calculation should be:
`var tickSize = fullSize / (scale.ticks.length * scale.stepSize);`

I'm using the new Dataset Controller Interface and Scale Interface to derive my customer Bar chart controller and TimeScale to modify 2 lines of code each in of these interface.

The code I changed is as below:
Under the new TimeScale interface:

```
buildTicks: function() {
    ...
    me.stepSize = stepSize;
    ...
};
```

Under the new *Chart.controllers.derivedBar* interface:

```
getRuler: function() {
    ...
    var tickSize = fullSize / (scale.ticks.length * scale.stepSize);
    ...
};
```

Check out the complete code here https://codepen.io/allentcm/pen/KqQGoE/